# asp.net database error cant connect and check password? simple validator

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, connection-string

```
bool lozinka() 
{
    int r = GridView1.Rows.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    { 
        if(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value==GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text)
            if (TextBox2.Text == GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text)
            {
                id = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text;
                p = Convert.ToInt32(id);
                exit;
            }

    }
    return false;

}
protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    if (lozinka())
        args.IsValid = true;
    else
        args.IsValid = false;
}
```

//this is the code that is error when i try to check password? when i try to log in this is custom validator for user name and password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 p=convert.ToInt32(id);
    return true
```

instead of exit!